# Why the interface references shows toString(), hashCode() and other Object’s method

Tags: java

If an interface does not extends Object class then why the interface references shows toString(), hashCode() and other Object’s method.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson The question seems clear enough to me - what part is not clear for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's the way the language is designed. Any class *implementing* the interface will definitely have `Object` as an ultimate ancestor, so at execution time, those methods will definitely be available.

This is specified in [JLS 9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2):

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and throws clause `t` corresponding to each public instance method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and throws clause `t` declared in `Object`, unless an abstract method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

Comment: **What does this means** 

"If an interface has no direct super-interfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless an abstract method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface."

**If I disassemble the class using javap it only shows explicit methods even I don't extend any super-interfaces?**

Comment: @SalilVNair: It's talking about the logical members of the interface, from the perspective of "What can I call on an expression of an interface type?"

Comment: Thanks It seems to be clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Any implementation of an interface will necessarily extend `Object`. For example:

```
SomeInterface foo = new ConcreteImplementation();
```

Here, `ConcreteImplementation` must extend `Object`, because it is the ultimate ancestor of all Java objects. Thus you can access all the public methods associated with the `Object` class through your `foo` variable.

Comment: But the foo variable is of type SomeInterface and no other methods which are not defined in it be accessible at runtime right? So Is there any abstract methods of Objects are maintained by JVM?

Comment: @SalilVNair The foo variable points to an object of type `ConcreteImplementation`. The fact that your store a reference to it in a `SomeInterface` variable is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, *everything* is a subclass of `Object`, even if it's not explicitly declared to be so. So you declare your interface, and then whatever class implements your interface must be a subclass of `Object`, because everything is.

And because it's a subclass of `Object`, it pulls in all the visible methods of `Object`, like `.toString()`.